# Spring 4.1.0 @PropertySource doesn't work

Tags: spring, annotations

I use this annotation @PropertySource, it can't work.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class ApplicationMongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Override
public String getDatabaseName() {
    return env.getProperty("mongo.dbname");
}

@Override
@Bean
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
    log.info("my mongo host is : " + env.getProperty("mongo.host"));
    return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(env.getProperty("mongo.host"), Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("mongo.port"))),
            Collections.singletonList(MongoCredential.createCredential(env.getProperty("mongo.username"),
                    env.getProperty("mongo.dbname"), env.getProperty("mongo.password").toCharArray())));
}
```

My config.properties look like this :

```
mongo.host=ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
mongo.port=27000
mongo.username=xxxx
mongo.password=xxxx
mongo.dbname=xxxxx
```

When I start up tomcat, it throw an exception

```
15-09-09 18:12:04.963[ INFO][ApplicationMongoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$774a4ef6:34] my mongo host is : null
15-09-09 18:12:05.272[ INFO][cluster:71] Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27000], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
15-09-09 18:12:06.181[ INFO][ContextLoader:325] Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3197 ms
15-09-09 18:12:06.451[ INFO][cluster:76] Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27000
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 more
```

Look at this picture: "my mongo host is : null". It can not analyze config.properties file.

I find the reason, but I don't know why.
It can't analyze this file because this file encoding is UTF-8, and I modify it to ANSI, it works.
I don't know why. Is this spring's bug?

Comment: To use a quote from the answer *".properties files are [per definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) ISO-8859-1 encoded. So I'm afraid you can't do that."*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't find that question before. And now I know. Thanks.